# How to convert MySQL date time into ISO 8601 date format without offset?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have following MySQL datetime:

`2012-04-13 09:45:36`

I am converting it into ISO 8601 date format using

```
date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime('2012-04-13 09:45:36'));
```

It gives me following output:

`2012-04-13T09:45:36+0100`

How can I get output without offset i.e. without +0100

I just want to get `2012-04-13T09:45:36`

Can datetime be affected if I get it after removing the offset?

Comment: cast it to a timestamp (which doesn't have a timezone), or set the session timezone to 0.

Comment: @danblack, sorry i don't understand. how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build the date format with the formatting parameter you need.

`date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime('2012-04-13 09:45:36'));` is the same as `date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO', strtotime('2012-04-13 09:45:36'));`. If you remove the `O` parameter (offset to GMT) you will get the result you need:

`date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime('2012-04-13 09:45:36'));`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.